# Xamarin IOS Share Items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I am working on an app embedding wkwebview in it. I need to implement share option similar to safari browser. I have tried using the share plugin from https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin, share plugin from Xamarin essential. But none of them gives all the options I can see in the safari browser. I am attaching 3 screenshots, two from safari, 1 from the plugin i tried using.

[part1 image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbdHn.jpg)

[image]

The third one is from the sample i have made.

[image]

You can clearly see, my app gives less options to share item.

Thanks

Comment: That library is deprecated, did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/xamarin/essentials/share?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Comment: I did as I said in the question.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you used along with the associated file types